# Trying to Combine Two Scatter Plots and Two Line Graphs with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a graph that lists the high and low temperature per city on a specific day, but it seems like the y axes are just overlapping instead of plotting the point along it.
Here is what I have:

```
fig, al = plt.subplots()
al.scatter(al_cities, al_min)
al.scatter(al_cities, al_max, c='red')
al.plot(al_cities, al_min, c='lightblue')
al.plot(al_cities, al_max, c='orange')
al.fill_between(al_cities, al_max, al_min, facecolor='gray', alpha=.3)
al.set_title('Highs and Lows in Alabama on January 10, 2016', fontsize=18)
al.set_xlabel('City', fontsize=14)
al.set_ylabel('Temperature', fontsize=14)
```

And this is what the graph looks like:
[y-axis jumps around between numbers and doesn't count upwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw09H.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because matplotlib classifies your **y-axis** values as **categorical** instead of **numeric continuous** values.

This might be because your list of `al_min` and `al_max` contain strings
 `['1','2','3']` instead of integers `[1,2,3]`.

All you have to do is convert the **strings** in the list **to integers**.
 You can do it like this:

```
al_min = list(map(int, al_min))
al_max = list(map(int, al_max))
```

**Here is an example using your code:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the data for the example
al_cities = ['Birmingham', 'Huntsville', 'Mobile', 'Montgomery']
al_min = ['36','34', '39', '38']
al_max = ['52', '50', '57', '55']

# Convert strings to integers
al_min = list(map(int, al_min))
al_max = list(map(int, al_max))

# Here is your code (unchanged)
fig, al = plt.subplots()
al.scatter(al_cities, al_min)
al.scatter(al_cities, al_max, c='red')
al.plot(al_cities, al_min, c='lightblue')
al.plot(al_cities, al_max, c='orange')
al.fill_between(al_cities, al_max, al_min, facecolor='gray', alpha=.3)
al.set_title('Highs and Lows in Alabama on January 10, 2016', fontsize=18)
al.set_xlabel('City', fontsize=14)
al.set_ylabel('Temperature', fontsize=14)
```

### OUTPUT:

[image: Temperature plot]

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know how you figured it out with so little to go off of, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not quite understand the problem, But I would like to suggest that you could use the normal plt.plot() rather than subplots if you just have one graph to show. (You could use errorbars to show max and min temperature)